# Ordering records by the number of associated records

Tags: sql, scope, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Users can submit resources and post comments.

I want to show the users who are most 'active' by selecting the users who have submitted resources and comments and order the results from the user that has submitted the most resources and comments combined to the least.

```
**Resource**
has_many :users, :through => :kits
has_many :kits
belongs_to :submitter, class_name: "User"

**User**
has_many :resources, :through => :kits
has_many :kits
has_many :submitted_resources, class_name: "Resource", foreign_key: "submitter_id"

**Kits**
belongs_to :resource
belongs_to :user

**Comments**
belongs_to :user
```

I am new to this kind of sql in Rails. How can I get this record set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need to add the comments association to the User model:

```
has_many :comments
```

With this, the simplest solution is to do this:

```
User.all.sort do |a,b|
   (a.submitted_resources.count + a.comments.count) <=> (b.submitted_resources.count + b.comments.count)
end
```

This will get very slow, so if you want to do better you will want to add counter caches. In a migration:

```
def up
  add_column :users, :submitted_resources_count, :integer
  add_column :users, :comments_count, :integer

  User.reset_column_information

  User.find_each do |u| 
    u.update_attributes! \
      :submitted_resources_count => u.submitted_resources.count,
      :comments_count => u.comments.count
  end
end

def down
  add_column :users, :submitted_resources_count
  add_column :users, :comments_count
end
```

Once you run this migration, you can change the original query to:

```
User.select('*, (submitted_resources_count + comments_count) AS activity_level').order('activity_level DESC')
```

This will very efficiently return all users in the proper order, and as a bonus each user will have a read-only attribute called `activity_level` that will give the exact submitted resources + comments count.

Comment: Thanks Tanzeeb, I have a question. 1. Should there be remove_column :users, :submitted_resources_count in the def down methods?  2. I get that I run this migration but the method User.find_each do |u| will be run only when the migration is run this time. So do I need to put this in a scope or put it somewhere else in the application to run whenever I need to find the most active user?

Comment: Great questions. 1) Yes. The down method should undo the up, and since the up creates two columns, down should remove them. 2) The update in the migration sets up the initial count, but does not need to be called ever again. Rails will automatically update any column matching the pattern *_count with the respective association's count. You can use the third query, User.select ..., as either a class method or a scope to pull the top users. Add a limit(1) to the end of the chain to get only the top user.